# Facing a ClientAbortException

Tags: java, servlets

There is a servlet code to download an excel/zip file from the production server to the local machine. When I click on the "Save" or "Open " button on the production server, it throws a ClientAbortException. The same code works well in Dev and UAT. Also this error appears not always. Below is the code for the same -

```
        response.setContentType("application/download"); 
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename= \""+ fileName +"\""); 
        fin = new FileInputStream(f);
        int size = fin.available();
        response.setContentLength(size); 
        byte[] ab = new byte[size];

        os = response.getOutputStream();

        int bytesread;

        do{
            bytesread = fin.read(ab,0,size);
            if(bytesread >-1) { 
                os.write(ab,0,bytesread );
            }
        } while(bytesread >-1);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
```

Comment: it might be helpful to post the relevant part of your stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

You may be running afoul of a HTML firewall device, which is something that would exist in a prod environment, but not in your test environments.

Also, your code will not scale very well. What will happen to your server if 500 users all try to download a 50 MB file at the same time?

You can build a scalable loop like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
int bytesRead = input.read(buffer);
while (bytesRead > 0) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    bytesRead = input.read(buffer);
}
```

Choose an appropriate `bufferSize`, say 20480 or thereabouts.

Comment: Thank you Steve. will see if it works on prod. Is there anything that could be causing this? Like browser oe versionincompatibility? Because when trying to save or open the excel ( when fails , i.e 50% of the times ) The excel gets corrupted. Also on production only one end user is using the excel reports.